# Getting error TLS not available when connect via StartTLS

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, tls

I am trying to configure TLS on my mail server (postfix+dovecot on debian).

But whenever I try to send via StartTLS, I've got this error message

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Vulcan0.hijackedbrain.com ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
starttls
454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
```

Here is my main.cf postfix, especially TLS parameters

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/myCert.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/RSA.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

I checked the certificate using `openssl verify`. It seems OK.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Most frequent cause is the lack of permissions to read the key/cert files.

Comment: I think I just found it.

I generated a new certificate without password. And now it works.

Comment: If you have your solution, please answer your own question so that the question will no longer show up as unanswered.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://serverfault.com/help/accepted-answer) below after 2 days so the readers know that the solution is works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I regenerated a new certificate and auto signed it. But this time WITHOUT a password. And now, it works!